# compilation error: record replacement of macro in Erlang

Tags: compilation, macros, erlang, record

This is the directory structure.

> src/
>     animal.hrl
>     people.hrl
>     data_animal.erl
>     data_people.erl
>     test.erl
>     test_macro.erl

animal.hrl

```
%% The record definition of animal.

-ifndef(ANIMAL).
-define(ANIMAL,true).

-record(animal,{
  id,
  animal_name,
  age
}).

-endif.
```

people.hrl

```
%% The record definition of people.

-ifndef(PEOPLE).
-define(PEOPLE,true).

-record(people,{
  id,
  people_name,
  age
}).

-endif.
```

data_animal.erl

```
%% The data file of animal.

-module(data_animal).
-include("animal.hrl").

%% API
-export([get/1,get_ids/0]).

get(1)->
  #animal{
    id=1,
    animal_name="cat",
    age=23
  };
get(2)->
  #animal{
    id=2,
    animal_name="dog",
    age=19
  };
get(3)->
  #animal{
    id=3,
    animal_name="tiger",
    age=23
  };
get(4)->
  #animal{
    id=4,
    animal_name="pig",
    age=19
  };
get(_)->
  undefined.

get_ids()->
  [1,2,3,4].
```

data_people.erl

```
%% The data file of people.

-module(data_people).
-include("people.hrl").

%% API
-export([get/1,get_ids/0]).

get(1)->
  #people{
    id=1,
    people_name="John",
    age=23
  };
get(2)->
  #people{
    id=2,
    people_name="Ken",
    age=19
  };
get(3)->
  #people{
    id=3,
    people_name="Tom",
    age=23
  };
get(4)->
  #people{
    id=4,
    people_name="Healthy",
    age=19
  };
get(_)->
  undefined.

get_ids()->
  [1,2,3,4].
```

Notice that, for `data_animal.erl` and `data_people.erl`, the parameter of `get/1`is the record's id of the return value, and the return value of `get_ids/0` is a list of `get/1`'s parameters.

test.erl

```
-module(test).

%% API
-export([get_animal_list/1,get_people_list/1]).

-include("animal.hrl").
-include("people.hrl").

get_animal_list(Age)->
  Fun=fun(Id,Acc)->
    case data_animal:get(Id) of
      #animal{age=Age}=Conf->
        [Conf|Acc];
      _->
        Acc
    end
      end,
  lists:foldl(Fun,[],data_animal:get_ids()).

get_people_list(Age)->
  Fun=fun(Id,Acc)->
    case data_people:get(Id) of
      #people{age=Age}=Conf->
        [Conf|Acc];
      _->
        Acc
    end
      end,
  lists:foldl(Fun,[],data_people:get_ids()).
```

I want to get the data of animal and people, whose ages are 23, so I write 2 functions, `get_animal_list/1, get_people_list/1`.

I run

```
1> c(data_animal),c(data_people),c(test).
{ok,test}
2> test:get_people_list(23).
[{people,3,"Tom",23},{people,1,"John",23}]
3> test:get_animal_list(23).
[{animal,3,"tiger",23},{animal,1,"cat",23}]
```

Suddenly, I find that the 2 functions share the same pattern. Then I attempt to write a macro `get_list`, and make 2 calls instead.

test_macro.erl

```
-module(test_macro).

%% API
-export([get_animal_list/1,get_people_list/1]).

-include("animal.hrl").
-include("people.hrl").

-define(get_list(DataMod,Record,Age),(
  Fun=fun(Id,Acc)->
    case DataMod:get(Id) of
      #Record{age=Age}=Conf->
        [Conf|Acc];
      _->
        Acc
    end
  end,
  lists:foldl(Fun,[],DataMod:get_ids())
)).

get_animal_list(Age)->
  ?get_list(data_animal,animal,Age).

get_people_list(Age)->
  ?get_list(data_people,people,Age).
```

But I got the compile error:

```
4> c(test_macro).
test_macro.erl:22: syntax error before: ','
test_macro.erl:25: syntax error before: ','
test_macro.erl:4: function get_animal_list/1 undefined
test_macro.erl:4: function get_people_list/1 undefined
error
```

Tell me why~y~y~

Thank you all!
I have 3 questions now.

1. Is my code really not Erlang-like? It's extracted from my company's project. Am I still thinking in OOP? Or so do the programming guys in my company?
2. Thanks to @mlambrichs 's advice. It works, but I still wonder why my code get the compilation error? Is it because Erlang preprocessor is a one-pass scanner, so it fails to recognize `#Record{age=Age}`?
3. According to @mlambrichs 's suggestion, I try to change the macro

   -define(get_list(DataMod, Record, Age),
     [P || P <- lists:map(fun(Id) -> DataMod:get(Id) end,
       DataMod:get_ids()),
       P#Record.age =:= Age]
   ).

into a function

```
get_list(DataMod, Record, Age)->
  [P || P <- lists:map(fun(Id) -> DataMod:get(Id) end,
    DataMod:get_ids()),
    P#Record.age =:= Age].
```

Then I get the compilation error:
`syntax error before: Record`

Comment: A note on style (which will probably fix your problem as a matter of course) define the records directly in the .erl files. Only have an `animal.erl` and a `people.erl` and write interface functions to the data so that they behave as their own abstract data types. To carry that further in Erlangdom (and make it OOP in the way Alan Kay intended) make `people.erl` and `animal.erl` modules define *processes*, so that each instance *is* an animal or a person. Write interface functions *to those processes* as accessors. In this way things like game servers are simplified in Erlang.

Comment: What I want to know is, why I got the compilation error? What's more, I'll appreciate if anybody can optimize my code without the use of lists:foldl/3.

Comment: It looks like a closing ")" is missing at the end of  the macro definition

Comment: No, there's a opening "(" just before the Fun definition that should be removed. If you add an extra ")" it won't work.

Comment: So you need someone to proofread your syntax for work or school, not actually coach you toward better Erlang in a more general sense. Very :-/

Comment: I have added the missing ")" in my code.

Comment: You should have removed that ')' in the macro. I've added answers to your 3 extra questions as well.

Comment: @Marc Lambrichs Note that there are 2 expressions in the macro definition. Shouldn't I wrap them with a pair of "()" ?

Comment: No, the macro is just a replacement.

Comment: But I might use the "return value" of the macro, that is, it may appear at the  right of the "=", so I should place a pair of "()".

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error is a misplaced '(' which should be removed:

```
-define(get_list(DataMod,Record,Age), (
                                     ^^^
   Fun=fun(Id,Acc)->              
     case DataMod:get(Id) of
        #Record{age=Age}=Conf->
           [Conf|Acc];
        _->
           Acc
     end
   end,
   lists:foldl(Fun,[],DataMod:get_ids())
).
```

> EDIT
>   You added some questions which I would like to start answering now.

- *Is my code really not Erlang-like?*

  - Usage of macros. There's no real need to use macros in your situation.
  - In general: you would like to hide the fact what kind of records are used in people and animals. That's implementation and should be shielded by your interface. You can just define a getter function that takes care of that in the right module. Pls. read my rewrite suggestions.
- *It works, but I still wonder why my code get the compilation error?* See top of answer.
- *....I try to change the macro ....* You're right, that function doesn't compile. Apparently a rewrite is needed.

Like this:

```
get_list(DataMod, Age) ->
    [ P || P = {_,_,_,A} <- lists:map(fun(Id) -> DataMod:get(Id) end,
           DataMod:get_ids()),
           A =:= Age].
```

> EDIT

Taking up a rewrite. What you want is a concatenation of two list in function test (yours test/0, mine test/1). Using a comma doesn't do that for you. ;-)

```
test(X)->
  ?get_list(data_animal,X) ++
  ?get_list(data_people,X).
```

Let's fix that get_list macro as well. Your macro definition get_list has 3 parameters, where it only needs 2. Why use Record as a parameter when you already use that in get_people_list/1 and get_animal_list/1? For example, try this:

```
-define(get_list(DataMod, Y),
   case DataMod of
      data_animal -> get_animal_list(Y);
      data_people -> get_people_list(Y);
      _Else -> []
   end
)
```

Overall, there is a lot of code replication in your test module. As a follow up to @yjcdll's advice, move the interface functions to animal and people to their own modules.

Let's have a look at your data modules and their get functions, as well.

I would suggest putting all people records in an array, in your case in the data_people module.

```
people() -> [
   #people{ id=1, people_name="John", age=23 },
   #people{ id=2, people_name="Ken", age=19 },
   #people{ id=3, people_name="Tom", age=23 },
   #people{ id=4, people_name="Healthy", age=19 } ].
```

Next, you would need a getter function to get only the people with a certain age:

```
get(Age) ->
   [X || X <- people(), is_age( X, Age )].
```

And the is_age/2 function would be:

```
is_age( Person, Age ) ->
   Person#people.age =:= Age.
```

So in module test your get_people_list/1 would get a lot simpler.

```
get_people_list(Age) ->
   data_people:get(Age).
```

And so on. Always be on the lookout for code that looks pretty much the same like code you've already used somewhere. Just try to behave as a sane, lazy programmer. Lazy = good. ;-)

EDIT: OP has to stick to modules given. So a rewrite of the macro is:

```
-define(get_list(DataMod, Record, Age),
   [P || P <- lists:map(fun(Id) -> DataMod:get(Id) end, 
                                   DataMod:get_ids()), 
         P#Record.age =:= Age]
).
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand. I cannot change the code structure, that is the distribution of data_*.erl and *.hrl. What I want to do is to abstract the common part of get_*_list functions and make a macro. Why the record name is not able to be replaced by the preprocessor.

Comment: Aha. Maybe this will help: -define(get_list(DataMod, Record, Age),
  [P || P <- lists:map(fun(Id) -> DataMod:get(Id) end, DataMod:get_ids()), P#Record.age =:= Age]
).